# Strange characters in Internet Explorer query string

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, url, internet-explorer-8

The problem occurs on a Wordpress site, although I don't suspect WP has anything to do with this problem.

In Chrome, IE10 and elsewhere the urls are fine, but in IE8 and IE9 the URLs looks like this:

```
?prac=&prov=gauteng%C2%AE%3D&listpage=1&search_field=none&value=
?prac=&prov=Gauteng®=&listpage=2&search_field=none&value=
```

It should look like this:

```
?prac=&prov=gauteng&listpage=1&search_field=none&value=
```

Note the `%C2%AE%3D` ® appended to the prov value. When I use IE10 developer tool and set the Document Mode to IE8 or IE9 the problem is visible - it's only when I set the Document mode to "standard" that the problem disappears.

Comment: A bit late but I managed to solve this.

Comment: Unfortunately my example Query strings above does not show the `&reg=` variable. I had a variable with the name **reg** so in the query string it looked like `&prov=Gauteng&reg=&listpage=2`. &reg; is the HTML equivalent of the Registered trademark, so IE < 10 does not respect this and even with  absence of the ;(semi colon) it assumes its a Registered trademark sign